# Multiple checkbox in php

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox

I have 4 checkboxes and suppose I check only two of them i.e user1 and user3

```
<input type="checkbox" name="usersp[]" value="1" checked="checked" />User1 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="usersp[]" value="2"/>User2 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="usersp[]" value="3" checked="checked" />User3 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="usersp[]" value="4"/>User4 <br>
```

and I have two fields ("User_id","Selected") in my database, below is my insert code

```
foreach($_POST['usersp'] as $user_id) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO sel_users(`User_id`,`Selected`) VALUES('$user_id','')";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

My question is how would I insert checked user as value of 1 and other as value of 0 in "Selected" field?

Comment: If your table sel_users is for selected users only, why do you need to insert users that haven't been selected? Surely, only inserting the selected users is the best course of action?

Comment: Instead of `<input type="checkbox" name="usersp[]" value="1" />`, use `<input type="hidden" name="usersp[1]" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" name="usersp[1]" value="1" />`.

Comment: The problem is when I use my update query, suppose I update these checkboxes and uncheck user1,user3 and check user2 and user4, then how would I make update query, because it also update and insert at the same time.

Comment: @DCoder Actually I am fetching all these users from database but I am trying through for loop.

Comment: That doesn't change the logic - generate a pair of inputs for each user ID, using that ID as the index in the input name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know the (unselected checkboxes) unless you are already know them

Here the only way that can make your dream real

```
//YOUR USERS IDS
$userIDS=array('1','2','3','4');
//CHECKED USERS ARRAY
$checkedUsers=array('1','3');

if(!isset($_POST['usersp'])){
foreach($userIDS as $userID){
    //IF IT IN CHECK ARRAY, CHECK IT!
    $checked=(in_array($userID,$checkedUsers))?' checked="checked"':'';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="usersp[]" value="'.$userID.'"'.$checked.' />';
}
}

else{
    foreach($userIDS as $userID){
        //USER SELECTED OR NOT?
        $selected=(in_array($userID,$_POST['usersp']))?'1':'0';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sel_users(`User_id`,`Selected`) VALUES('$user_id','$selected')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am using in my way, but it helps me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You will get the value of checked checkbox, and not get value of not checked checkbox.

use this tutorials

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

[determine whether checkbox is checked php $_GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488270/determine-whether-checkbox-is-checked-php-get)

Answer (score 1):

`Checkbox` gives the value of the `Checked` elements under the same name.

So in the example you have given You will not get the unchecked values.

But if you give each checkbox a different name then you can achieve what you want like :-

```
<input type="checkbox" name="usersp1" value="1" checked="checked" />User1 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="usersp2" value="2"   />User2 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="usersp3" value="3" checked="checked" />User3 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="usersp4" value="4"   />User4 <br>
```

And On PHP side

```
for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
    if(isset($_POST['usersp'.$i]){
         $sql = "INSERT INTO sel_users(`User_id`,`Selected`) VALUES('$user_id','1')";
         $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    else{
        //Somehow you still have to get other User_id's in another way.
    }
}
```

Now you haw to get unselected user ID form somewhere else which you can put into the else condition.
You can use Ajax + JS or JQuery for form submission instead of default HTML one so that you can prvice the unchecked values under another name and process them in PHP accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Work for me, save both check and uncheck value to mysql

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="jawab25.php">
<input type="hidden" name="check_lista[]" value="<?php echo $r["id"]?>">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_listb[]" value="<?php echo $r["id"]?>">
<input value="Check" type="Submit">
```

jawab25.php :

```
    foreach($_POST['check_lista'] as $itema){
        $string="update trans set ck='N' where id='$itema'";
        $tampil=mysql_query($string);
    }

    foreach($_POST['check_listb'] as $itemb){
        $string="update trans set ck='Y' where id='$itemb'";
        $tampil=mysql_query($string);
    }
```