# post checkbox values to a php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, checkbox

I'm trying to write a script to post with jQuery checkboxes ids that are checked(for php deletion script).

I have something like this

```
   <form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="id" value='1'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="id" value='2'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="id" value='3'>
    <input type="button" name="DELETE" id="DELETE">
     </form>
```

So I want to post those values(ids) to a php file delete.php, how can I achieve this?

Comment: multiple dom elements in a page are not supposed to have same id attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wanted to achieve this through using jQuery ajax call to post to php

**Html**

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id" value='1'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id" value='2'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id" value='3'>
    <input type="button" name="DELETE" id="DELETE">
</form>
```

**Javascript with jQuery**

```
var selected_values = $("input[name='id[]']:checked");
```

**Directly post to delete.php**

```
<?php
    // $_POST['id'] will return an array.
    $selected_values = $_POST['id'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value='1'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value='2'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value='3'>
    <input type="button" name="DELETE" id="DELETE">
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#delete").click(function(){

        var data = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
             return this.value;
        }).get();


        var dataString = "imgList="+ data;

       $.post('delete.php',dataString,function(theResponse){
       //// Check theResponse
       });               


   });      
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$imgList = $_REQUEST['imgList'];

$i = 0;

$token = strtok($imgList, ","); 

$imgArray = array();

while ($token != false){

    $imgArray[$i] = (string)$token;

    $token = strtok(",");

    $i++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do. send the form collection to the php page.  make sure your input and other elements you unique id.

```
<form action="yourUrl/Method" Method="POST"> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="id1" value='1'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="id2" value='2'>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="id3" value='3'>
    <input type="button" name="DELETE" id="DELETE">
</form>
```

then in PHP access Request object and use those values.

Answer (score 0):

Single check box

```
<form action="checkbox-form.php" method="post">
    Do you need wheelchair access?
    <input type="checkbox" name="formWheelchair" value="Yes" />
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In the PHP script, we can get the submitted option from the $_POST array. If $_POST['formWheelchair'] is “Yes”, then the box was checked. If the check box was not checked, $_POST['formWheelchair'] won’t be set.

Here’s an example of PHP handling the form:

```
<?php

      if(isset($_POST['formWheelchair']) && 
      $_POST['formWheelchair'] == 'Yes') 
      {
          echo "Need wheelchair access.";
      }
     else
      {
          echo "Do not Need wheelchair access.";
      }  

  ?>
```

The value of $_POST['formSubmit'] is set to ‘Yes’ since the value attribute in the input tag is ‘Yes’.

You can set the value to be a ’1′ or ‘on’ instead of ‘Yes’. Make sure the check in the PHP code is also updated accordingly.

Furthemore information at below articles.

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

[determine whether checkbox is checked php $_GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488270/determine-whether-checkbox-is-checked-php-get)

Hope it helps